# Text Area with [Object object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forms

I created a component for my form, it looks like this

```
import React from "react";

export default function TextArea(name, value, onChange) {
  return (
    <div className="mt-1">
      <textarea
        rows={3}
        className="mt1 block w-full py-1.5 px-3 rounded-md border-2 border-orange-light"
        placeholder="Digite"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        name={name}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when I use it, it stays in an [object object], inside this textarea

[image: But when I use it, it stays in an [object object], inside this textarea]

I'm using it on my form this way

```
 <TextArea
    name="about"
    value={about}
    onChange={(e) => setAbout(e.target.value)} />
```

Can anyone tell what I should do to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: well, `about` is an object, and you didn't specify what property of that object you wanted in the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct TextArea Component code, please try this and it will resolve your issue :)

```html
import React from "react";

export default function TextArea({ name, value, onChange }) {
  return (
    <div className="mt-1">
      <textarea
        rows={3}
        className="mt1 block w-full py-1.5 px-3 rounded-md border-2 border-orange-light"
        placeholder="Digite"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        name={name}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First do `console.log(value)` and find out what is in object , later use it like below  with whichever property name your object got.

```
 value={value.propertyname}
```

Answer (score 0):

What parameter do you pass to 'value'?
Most likely, what is being passed to the 'value' is an object, check that first so I can help you better.

**UPDATE**

when declaring the about, maybe it's being declared so that it stays as an object.
then declare as:

```
const [about, setAbout] = useState("");
<TextArea
...,
value={about},
...
>
```

Comment: `<form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e, {
                email, title, job, state, city, about, tel, wpp, insta, fb, linkedin
              })}`
My about is this, i am used in my form

Comment: This 'Value' you are passing to the <TextArea...> is being passed as **Object**, as this variable is being declared or what is being passed to it before that.